# byName Annotation based Autowiring (Spring3)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create spring-mvc project.

My "Repository" component is defined as

```
@Repository("testEntityDao")
public class TestEntityDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<TestEntity> implements TestEntityDao {
```

"Service" component with instance of TestEntityDao

```
@Service("testManager")
public class TestManagerServiceImpl implements TestManagerService{
    @Autowired
    TestEntityDao testEntityDao;
```

TestManagerServiceImpl doesn't have any constructor defined and it also doesn't have getter and setter for testEntityDao. (I tried code after writing setter, but got same error).


ApplicationContext.xml has following line to enable autowiring byName

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    .
    .
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package= .... />
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Error that I am getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.cms.dao.TestEntityDao com.test.cms.service.impl.TestManagerServiceImpl.testEntityDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.cms.dao.TestEntityDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=testEntityDao)}
```

How to resolve this error ?

Comment: What package did you specify in base package parameter?

Comment: all package with "@" spring annotation is in base package (this include package having TestEntityDaoImpl and TestManagerServiceImpl)

Comment: <context:component-scan
  base-package="com.test.cms.bservice.impl,
   com.test.cms.controller,
   com.test.cms.db.dao.impl,
   com.test.cms.db.domain,
   com.test.cms.service.impl"/>

It doesn't have interface package. Should i include them too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer to common parent package instead of all these packages. Make your component scan as:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.cms"/>
```

Comment: It worked Prasad.  It only means i am missing sth while writing pkg in base-pkg. I will use this. More clear and easy to write. Thanks.